Flutter build ios error when building with Android Studio or Visual Studio
I received an error when trying to build a Flutter app using AS/VS
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found
/Users/thanhnd/Projects/Flutter/flutter_tax_free/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8

But when I build with Xcode everything works fine.
How can I build a Flutter application using AS/VS?
Thanks!

Try flutter pub get  and then pod install then run your project

@Ahmadhassan I tried it before asking but it didn't work

try a flutter clean, and the run again flutter pug get & flutter run

Try deleting ios>pods folder, and podfile.lock. cd into ios folder, then run flutter pod update, then pod install, then flutter run

I found the problem already.
It was because I set the wrong configuration in Xcode. Yesterday I set it to DEV instead of dev.
Thanks for your help, everyone!

